# DSL-Json @compiledJson bean instantiation error

Tags: java, json, dsl

I'm using DSL-Json and want to serialize a Class Object using serialize() of DSlJson. I've installed Mono on MAC so that I don't miss anything during build. The maven build hangs most of the time and I see the following errors:

```
 /Users/<workspace_path>/DSLIntegration/target/classes/dsl_json/json/ExternalSerialization.java:[869,81] a.b.c.Example.Model.**Abstract is abstract; cannot be instantiated**
 /Users/<workspace_path>/DSLIntegration/target/classes/dsl_json/json/ExternalSerialization.java:[877,73] a.b.c.Example.Model.**Abstract is abstract; cannot be instantiated**
```

I'm using the same code as given in the Github link of DSL-Json : [https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json]

Can someone please help me resolve this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that

```
public Abstract abs;
```

is giving you grief. This might be only possible if you don't have latest compiler for databinding. If that is the case, try commenting out that property (and cleaning up code which references it) to see if it's working without abstract class feature (this should be supported in really old versions).

If it's working in that case most probably Maven didn't download the latest compiler (it should do that unless specified otherwise).

You can download it manually from: https://compiler.dsl-platform.com:8443/platform/download/dsl-compiler.zip

and specify it in pom.xml with

```
<configuration>
  <annotationProcessors>
  <annotationProcessor>com.dslplatform.json.CompiledJsonProcessor</annotationProcessor>
  </annotationProcessors>
  <compilerArguments>
    <Adsljson.compiler>path_to_compiler/dsl-compiler.exe</Adsljson.compiler>
  </compilerArguments>
</configuration>
```

If you specify incorrect path, Maven will block with a prompt, so you should try it from console first.

I was unable to reproduce your issue on MAC, but I added detailed logging option for debugging such issues. Try updating processor dependency to v0.9 and enable DEBUG logging for detailed info: https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/blob/master/examples/Maven/pom.xml#L35
Note that javac output is not visible in Maven, so try compiling it within IntelliJ which shows javac output.

Comment: Hi, I was able to resolve the above error but now I'm getting **Unable to serialize provided object. Failed to find serializer for: class java.lang.Class**. ExternalSerialization.java is generated and mvn build is successful

Comment: You are getting that for vanilla example or for your custom code? Show the code if it's something custom.

Comment: For custom code - please refer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122711/resdsl-json-with-resteasy-getting-nomessagebodywriterfoundfailure-error?noredirect=1#comment61806001_37122711