# DSL-Json with RESTEasy - Getting NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure error

Tags: java, json, resteasy, dsl

I'm integrating RestEasy with Dsl-JSON but I'm getting the following error:

> Failed executing GET /json/sample/get         org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type

My code is as below:

```
@Path("/json/sample")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Sample getProductInJSON() {

        Sample product = new Sample();
        product.setName("abcd");
        product.setAge(12);

        return product; 
    }
}
```

My pom looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dslplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsl-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dslplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsl-json-processor</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessors>                  <annotationProcessor>com.dslplatform.json.CompiledJsonProcessor</annotationProcessor>
            </annotationProcessors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The same rest endpoint was working with Jackson but I want to use DSL-Json and integrate it with RestEasy. The mvn build is succcesful and I see the `ExternalSerialization` class being generated for all the `@CompiledJson` objects.

I'm passing application/json in the headers.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

The messageBodyReader class is as below:

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class MyMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        System.out.println("isWriteable called...");
        return  Sample.class == type; 
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Object arg0, Class<?> arg1, Type arg2,
            Annotation[] arg3, MediaType arg4) {
        return -1;
    }


    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
            OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter();
        entityStream.write(writer.getByteBuffer());     
    }
}
```

And MyMessageBodyReader is like this:

```
@Provider
public class MyMessageBodyReader extends DslJson implements    MessageBodyReader<Object> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        return "Successfuly read ";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> arg0, Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2,
            MediaType arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm unable to invoke these Providers when the rest endpoint is hit, I tried using
Application Class getClasses method:

```
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(MyMessageBodyReader.class);
    classes.add(MyMessageBodyWriter.class);
    return classes;
}
```

But it's not registering these classes.

RestEasy Configuration : web.xml file

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>com.x.y.rest.JSONService</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You need to write a custom `MessageBodyWriter` using that library. When you use Jackson, it has it's own `MessagebodyWriter`. If you want to use a different serialziation library that doesn't have one, you need to write your own

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I referred to this (https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/creating-a-simple-jax-rs-messagebodywriter.html) but couldnt resolve the error.

Comment: Can you show your attempt at creating your own writer. I have never used the library you are using, so I can't really give much of an example. Also are you sure the writer is registered?

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Or is it something different?

Comment: Like I said, I've never used the library, but looking at [this example](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/blob/master/examples/Maven/src/main/java/com/dslplatform/maven/Example.java#L46), you need to create the `DslJson` object, which gets populated with the META-INF/services info, and from there, you need to serialize using `DslJson.serialize(writer, obj)`

Comment: Also can you show your complete RESTEasy configuration

Comment: You need to register the provider in your web.xml, as that's where you are registering your resource classes. `resteasy.providers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the Spring integration for DSL-JSON at the [Revenj library](https://github.com/ngs-doo/revenj/blob/master/java/revenj-spring/src/main/java/org/revenj/spring/DslJsonMessageConverter.java).
It also has a wrapper around DslJson so it can access readers and writers directly.

I don't have experience with Resteasy, but if you have code somewhere online on Github, I can take a look at it later.

Comment: So basically Im trying to integrate RestEasy with DSL-Json using custom MessageBodyReader and MessageBodyWriter. If you know how to do, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use CompiledJson with Enums?

Comment: They should work if they have empty ctor. I forgot to add support for enums with ctor arguments. Will do that today or tomorrow. https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/blob/master/processor/src/test/java/com/dslplatform/json/ValidationTest.java#L58

Comment: okay, sure, I will follow up. It gives me error when using RestEasy, It works properly when I use Jackson (de)/serializers, I want to use with DSL JSON (de)/serializer methods.

Comment: I've released processor v1.0. It should now work as expected

Comment: With v1.0, I see this error - java.io.IOException: Unknown enum value: 'ANDRIOD' at position 54
14:22:52,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)  at dsl_json.json.ExternalSerialization.deserialize(ExternalSerialization.java:1172) ExternalSerialization does contain the hash of ANDROID

Comment: Please submit an issue to the Github with the problematic model and I'll fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111614/discussion-between-user2340345-and-rikard-pavelic).